# The linked image cannot be displayed - where is the link kept?

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with lots of pictures in it.  The pictures always displayed okay until today.
All the pictures now display the error `The linked image cannot be displayed.  The file may have been moved, renamed or deleted.  Verify that the link points to the correct file and location`

Where can I find where the link points to?
I have checked that the pictures still exist in the folders, so i'm not sure what has happened.
If I click on the picture, the name box displays Picture 25, but there is no file path in the formula bar or when I check through the properties.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click on the picture and select Hyperlink to show the path.

Comment: Thanks BirdMan, but there is no hyperlink.  I tested by inserting another picture and there is nothing for that one either.